# Can not read property "__" of undefined

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, angular-meteor

I am currently working for my school project and using Meteor with AngularJs 1 and ES6. In one of my views I try to update some live data (with AngularCharts) every second which are currently randomly generated. I am new to the way of how Meteor and ES6 works, so I think a have a pretty easy error.

This is my code of the class from the view:

```
class View2 {

constructor($interval, $scope) {
    'ngInject';

    this.cardRow = [
        {name: 'Drilling Heat', color: 'white', value: 0},
        {name: 'Drilling Speed', color: 'white', value: 0},
        {name: 'Milling Heat', color: 'white', value: 0},
        {name: 'Milling Speed', color: 'white', value: 0}
    ];
    this.type = ['bar', 'line', 'pie', 'doughnut', 'radar'];
    this.chartRow = [
        {
            name: 'Chart1',
            type: 'bar',
            labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            series: ['Series A'],
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            datasetOverride: [{yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'}],
            options: {
                animation: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            id: 'y-axis-1',
                            type: 'linear',
                            display: true,
                            position: 'left'

                        }]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Chart2',
            type: 'line',
            labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            series: ['Series A'],
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            datasetOverride: [{yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'}],
            options: {
                animation: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            id: 'y-axis-1',
                            type: 'linear',
                            display: true,
                            position: 'left'

                        }]
                }
            }
        }
    ];


    $interval(this.update, 1000);
}

update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cardRow.length; i++) {
        this.cardRow[i].value = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10);
        var value = this.cardRow[i].value;
        switch (true) {
            case (value > 80):
                this.cardRow[i].color = 'red';
                break;
            case (value > 60):
                this.cardRow[i].color = 'orange';
                break;
            case (value > 40):
                this.cardRow[i].color = 'yellow';
                break;
            default:
                this.cardRow[i].color = 'green';
                break;
        }
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < this.chartRow.length; y++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < this.chartRow[y].data.length; z++) {
            this.chartRow[y].data[z] = this.chartRow[y].data[z + 1];
        }
        this.chartRow[y].data[z - 1] = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10);
    }
}
```

}

The $interval should call the function "update" every second but then the variable is unknown. it throws an error like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at update (view2.js:74)
at callback (modules.js?hash=7db65c4…:46346)
at Scope.$eval (modules.js?hash=7db65c4…:51381)
at Scope.$digest (modules.js?hash=7db65c4…:51194)
at Scope.$apply (modules.js?hash=7db65c4…:51489)
at tick (modules.js?hash=7db65c4…:46336)
```

What can I do to solve this problem? And is there a way to use Meteor with the old Javascript Version?

Comment: `$interval(this.update, 1000);` => `$interval(() => this.update(), 1000);`

Comment: Yeah.... I expected such an easy mistake. Thank you!